# Dropdown with links: Saving state in local storage

Tags: forms, select, local-storage, dropdown

I'd like to create a dropdown with links and save the dropdown state in local storage.

This is the code for the dropdown.

```
<select id="sort"> 
    <option value="">Please choose…</option> 
    <option value="?sort[date_created]=ASC">Sort by Date (ASC)</option> 
    <option value="?sort[date_created]=DESC">Sort by Date (DESC)</option> 
</select>

<script> 
document.getElementById("sort").onchange = function() { if (this.selectedIndex!==0) { window.location.href = this.value; }}; 
</script>
```

I have created the dropdown and everything works fine with the links, but I want to save the current selection. So when the page is reloaded, the selection in the dropdown should remain saved.

**UPDATE:**

I used this code now. But both links in the dropdown values did not work (I tested it with https://… and the page was just reloaded):

```js
function choose(what) { document.getElementById("sort").value = what; }
    

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('sort')) {
        choose(localStorage('sort'));
    }
}); 
    

document.getElementById("sort").onchange = function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
        localStorage.setItem('sort', this.value);
        window.location.reload();
    }
};
```

```html
<select id="sort"> 
    <option value="">Please choose…</option> 
    <option value="?sort[date_created]=ASC">Sort by Date (ASC)</option> 
    <option value="?sort[date_created]=DESC">Sort by Date (DESC)</option> 
</select>
```

**UPDATE:**

I added this code now, but it simply reloads the page without calling the links (I have replaced the links with apple.com and microsoft.com for testing purposes only).

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            function choose(what) {
                document.getElementById("sort").value = what;
            }
    

                if (localStorage.getItem('sort')) {
                    choose(localStorage.getItem('sort'));
                }
    

            document.getElementById("sort").onchange = function() {
                if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
                    localStorage.setItem('sort', this.value);
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            };
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="sort"> 
            <option value="">Please choose…</option> 
            <option value="https://apple.com">Sort by Date (ASC)</option>
            <option value="https://microsoft.com">Sort by Date (DESC)</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two sub-problems to solve in order to solve the issue you want.

First: How to set the value of `select` to the one you desire. Basically you will either put a `select` attribute to the `option` of your choice when the markup is being defined, or you find the select element and change its value. The snippet below does the latter, but you can use the former as well as long as you are fine doing this logic on the server-side. Since you did not specify anything about your server, I will only illustrate the client-side-only solution, but it's important to note it's not the only possible option.

```js
function choose(what) {
    document.getElementById("sort").value = what;
}
```

```html
<select id="sort"> 
    <option value="">Please choose…</option> 
    <option value="?sort[date_created]=ASC">Sort by Date (ASC)</option> 
    <option value="?sort[date_created]=DESC">Sort by Date (DESC)</option> 
</select>

<input type="button" onclick="choose('')" value="Please choose">
<input type="button" onclick="choose('?sort[date_created]=ASC')" value="Sort by Date (ASC)">
<input type="button" onclick="choose('?sort[date_created]=DESC')" value="Sort by Date (DESC)">
```

Here we can see a `function` called `choose` that receives `what` to `choose` and then proceeds with finding the HTML element and changing its `value` to that. We have some `input` elements with `type` being `button` for illustration purpose that this works.

Second: How to save and load values in the `localStorage`. Basically you can read from the `localStorage` via `localStorage.getItem("someitem")` and write into it via `localStorage.setItem("someitem", somevalue)`.

So, in your case the change handler could have

```
localStorage.setItem("sort", this.value);
```

before any redirects so `localStorage` would have the value. Then, you could do something like this upon page load

```
if (localStorage.getItem("sort")) {
    choose(localStorage.getItem("sort"));
}
```

So, if there is a truey value for this item, then you change the value to it.

EDIT

Okay. So you have defined the function. That's good progress already. Now, add the following:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('sort')) {
        choose(localStorage.getItem('sort'));
    }
});
```

This will make sure that if there is a truey value inside `localStorage` corresponding to the key of `sort`, then it's applying it. Now, let's change your change event as follows:

```
document.getElementById("sort").onchange = function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
        localStorage.setItem('sort', this.value);
        window.location.reload();
    }
};
```

and test.

EDIT

Okay, there were further typos on my part, so I have implemented a fully functioning example that can be seen here:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            function choose(what) {
                document.getElementById("sort").value = what;
            }
    

                if (localStorage.getItem('sort')) {
                    choose(localStorage.getItem('sort'));
                }
    

            document.getElementById("sort").onchange = function() {
                if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
                    localStorage.setItem('sort', this.value);
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            };
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="sort"> 
            <option value="">Please choose…</option> 
            <option value="?sort[date_created]=ASC">Sort by Date (ASC)</option>
            <option value="?sort[date_created]=DESC">Sort by Date (DESC)</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT

Snippet to redirect to the choice of the option:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            document.getElementById("sort").onchange = function() {
                if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
                     window.location.href = this.value;
                }
            };
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="sort"> 
            <option value="">Please choose…</option> 
            <option value="https://apple.com">Sort by Date (ASC)</option>
            <option value="https://microsoft.com">Sort by Date (DESC)</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: As per the discussion in the comment-section, following the ideas discussed in this answer led to a solution after all, the current code being

```js
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            function choose(what) {
                document.getElementById("sort").value = what;
            }
    

                if (localStorage.getItem('sort')) {
                    choose(localStorage.getItem('sort'));
                }
    

            document.getElementById("sort").onchange = function() {
                if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
                    localStorage.setItem('sort', this.value);
                    window.location.href = this.value;
                }
            };
        });
```

```html
<select id="sort"> 
  <option value="">Please choose…</option> 
  <option value="?SORTBY=DATE-ASC">Sort by Date (ASC)</option>
  <option value="?SORTBY=DATE-DESC">Sort by Date (DESC)</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Okay, I am new to Javascript… 
What do I have to do if I want it on the client side? Or is it better to do it with a cookie?

Comment: @Michael78sth the above is a complete answer to your question. Have you tried applying it? If so, did you stumble into a problem? If so, can you provide the details of the problem you have stumbled into?

Comment: Okay, I added the code like this: 

`<select id="sort"> 
    <option value="">Please choose…</option> 
    <option value="?sort[date_created]=ASC">Sort by Date (ASC)</option> 
    <option value="?sort[date_created]=DESC">Sort by Date (DESC)</option> 
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
function choose(what) {
 document.getElementById("sort").value = what;
}
</script>`

But it doesn't open the links. Could you please add the complete code snippet here? Sorry, my JavaScript know-how is limited. 

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Michael78sth I cannot add a complete snippet, because SO will not allow us to directly manipulate the `localStorage`. But I will look into your example.

Comment: @Michael78sth I have edited my answer based on your comment. I have given you a way to get your local storage value and an adjustment to properly store it and reload the page.

Comment: @Michael78sth Sure thing. If this solves the issue for you, then you might consider accepting this answer as the correct answer. If not, then let me know what the next obstacle is.

Comment: I think I am doing something completely wrong. Do I have to add all of the three code blocks into a JavaScript file? The first with the function "function choose(what)" plus the "window.addEventListener('load', function()" and the "document.getElementById("sort").onchange = function()"?

Sorry, I am pretty new to JS.

Comment: Yes, try adding all of these. If you stumble into a problem, edit your question, update it with your current try and how it fails. Don't worry about being new to JS, we've all been there.

Comment: Thanks Lajos. I did it, but I got an error: I got an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: @Michael78sth there is no reference to any `$` in the code I have written, so your error stems from somewhere else

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up two code snippets. I used the code from you and got an error message: "message": "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 20,
  "colno": 5

Comment: @Michael78sth you are running it in an environment that does not allow to refer to localStorage. Try in your page instead. Snippets are displayed in iframes and browsers tend to panic when you want to refer localStorage from inside iframes, this is why you get a security error. Try it in your HTML instead without iframes.

Comment: I tested it on my website. But both links in the dropdown did not work (I tested it with https://… and the page was just reloaded).

Comment: @Michael78sth I had a typo in my code, there was `choose(localStorage('sort'));`, but in fact it should have been `choose(localStorage.getItem('sort'));`. I have edited my answer to fix this. Can you check again? Also, using the Dev Tools you can see error messages if there is an error.

Comment: Thank you for the review. I have changed the code as you described. However, when I select a value from the drop-down list, the page simply reloads. But the links that are defined in the option value are not called. And there is no error.

Comment: @Michael78sth you are right, there were some further typos on my part. So I have made some fixes and tested the changes. It works now. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I still have the same problem. The page simply reloads without calling the links.

Comment: @Michael78sth earlier there were typos on my part, but the latest code I have written and which you can find at the end of my answer was tested and it worked. So there must be something wrong in your testing or maybe you tested an earlier code. Please try running the HTML I have shared and only that. It should work.

Comment: Yes, I copied the new code and tested the new version. I replaced both links in the option value with links like https://domain1.com and https://domain2.com and it still does not work. The page keeps simply reloading but it does not call the links.

Comment: @Michael78sth I have a hypothesis about what could have gone wrong for you. Can you edit your question and add the full HTML code of what you were trying now? If so, let me know when you have added it to your question here in the comment section.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I added the current code here.

Comment: @Michael78sth no worries. I pasted your code into my HTML file and tested it. And it worked, i.e., changing the dropdown to an option reloaded the page and has successfully set the dropdown to the option chosen before the reload. You say the links are not "called" in your edit. Is some other additional expectation that you need?

Comment: Okay, thanks for testing. The purpose was that the dropdown selection would call the link defined in the option value (e.g. ?sort[date_created]=asc) or apple(dot)com). But it does not work.

Comment: @Michael78sth when the page is being reloaded, the chosen option is successfully chosen. I believe you also had an additional goal when you mention "calling" the link, but I'm not sure about the further expectation. Do you want to open a new tab/window and load that link? Or do you want to redirect to that link? What is the aim you want to achieve when you mention "calling" the link?

Comment: Yes, I want the links to be opened (in the same page) when I change the value of the dropdown. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Michael78sth then storing in local storage, reloading the page and redirecting is superfluous. I have created a snippet which redirects to the link without localStorage changes or so (you might see the browser not displaying the page under iframe, but this is not a problem for you if you do not do it in an iframe). If you for some reason need localStorage and page reload and redirect afterwards, then add `window.location.href = localStorage.getItem('sort');` to `choose`.

Comment: Thank you very much. The links in the dropdown are working now, but it does not store the current state in local memory. The links in the final dropdown version would be as follows: value="=SORT-BY-DATE-ASC" or value="=SORT-BY-DATE-DESC". I have only tested it with Apple.com and Microsoft.com. What do I need to add to save the dropdown selection? Thanks again.

Comment: @Michael78sth You can set the local state by running `localStorage.setItem('sort', this.value)` inside the `onchange` event.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I did it and posted the final code above.

Comment: @Michael78sth I'm happy you've got it working. I have edited my answer to reflect this. You may consider accepting this as the correct answer now that it's working according to your expectations.

Comment: Sure, will do so. How can I accept your code as the correct answer?

Comment: @Michael78sth besides the answer there is a check marc icon. If you click on it, then it will turn green and the answer is marked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
This is the final code, that is working…

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

function choose(what) {
    document.getElementById("sort").value = what;
}

if (localStorage.getItem('sort')) {
    choose(localStorage.getItem('sort'));
}

document.getElementById("sort").onchange = function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
        localStorage.setItem('sort', this.value);
        window.location.href = this.value;
    }
};
});
```

```html
<select id="sort">
<option value="">Please choose…</option> 
<option value="?SORTBY=DATE-ASC">Sort by Date (ASC)</option>
<option value="?SORTBY=DATE-DESC">Sort by Date (DESC)</option>
</select>
```